# Wordpress error establishing a database connection when clone to test subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress

I was tried to clone my Wordpress to subdomain and changed this line from example.com to test.example.com:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'test.example.com'); // <- this line
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

But after that my site on subdomain call: Error establishing a database connection.
My wp-config.php file declare correct the database information (tested with mysql_connect() function).
How to fix it??

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use the same database for two Wordpress installations? The main Wordpress and the Wordpress on subdomain?

Create a new database and note the name, username of the user associated with the database with all privileges and the password of the user. Take a backup of your main database and import the backup in your new database.

Then in your new database, find `wp_options` and change `site_url` and `home_url` to your subdomain.

Then as @F5 Buddy said, change the following in your config.php

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
```

Try and access the admin panel by going to `subdomain/wp-admin`. See if that works. Login using your main Wordpress username and password. Once logged into the admin panel, don't forget to refresh the Permalinks by going to `Settings -> Permalinks` and clicking on Save; otherwise only your homepage will be linked correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I solved this problem, just change
define('MULTISITE', true);
to
define('MULTISITE', false);
Thanks for this helps. :)

Comment: Good to hear @Tyler Tran

Answer (score 1):

### First you have to configure wp-config.php in root directory

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

After that you have to change site_url and home_url in database table "wp_options" then run again.